# Laravel ->with method working local but not on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a function in my controller that sends a message using the 'with' method. It works perfectly in my local environment but not in production.

Here is the function I use in my controller:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('successMsg',trans('users.badges_reset'));
```

And this is the function i use in my view

```
@if(Session::has('successMsg'))
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <i class="fas fa-check"></i> {{Session::get('successMsg')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

The view component is loaded in my other templates via include. I debugged the session but it doesn't show up.

Comment: what type of error you get on production